# Dice rolling through a string

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that takes the string `"1d8"` and make the program identify it as `int i = (Int) ((Math.Random()*8)+1)` one time. It would also be nice if I could make it identify `"10d8"` to do something like :

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){    
    int j += (int) ((Math.Random()*8)+1);
}
```

Thus returning basically the roll of 10 eight sided dice. So my question is how do I get the code to recognize the numbers on either side of the character d and make this work with whatever roll I do.

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Comment: You can also split the string using `"d"` as a delimiter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) method of the String class.

```
String s = "10d8";
String[] numbers = s.split("d");
```

`numbers[0]` will have 10 and `numbers[1]` will have 8

Comment: Wow that was quick thanks I'm fairly new to java so I had no clue I could do this thanks.